# "Unidentified network" only on wifi and if connected to my provider

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, internet

I can't connect to internet using the router that my internet provider (Vodafone, Italy) gave to me (Vodafone station). This happens *only* using the wifi connection, and *only* using the router and internet connection of my provider. I have no problem with the internet connection of a friend of mine. This problem happens only with one notebook, with Windows Vista. Internet works with another notebook of  mine with Windows 7 on it.

Windows tells me the network is unidentified. I can manually change the connection type from "public" to "private", but nothing changes, still no internet connection. The connection between the device and the router is established, the device is recognized by the router and an ip is assigned. There's no restriction on the number of wifi devices. I tried to reinstall the drivers and disable windows firewall, but nothing. It does not work also in safe mode.

Ip and dns are obtained automatically. Proxy is disabled. `ipconfig /all` on both my notebooks returns me the same informations.

Please help me.

Comment: [Troubleshoot network connection problems](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/troubleshoot-network-connection-problems)

Comment: @DavidPostill: I already done all the standard tests.